# Redirect PHP script with argument to shell command line

Tags: php, shell, command-line

I have a shell commandline call that needs a PHP script with an inline argument inputted to it via this method in laravel tinker;

```
php7.1 artisan tinker < phpscript.php 50000
```

Problem is that when executed, it's returning an error;

```
PHP Warning:  include(50000): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /vol/code/prod/cep/vendor/psy/psysh/src/ExecutionLoop.php on line 48
```

If I run the PHP script alone with the arg...it is able to see the 50000 as $argv[1]. Anyone know how I can do this same thing via the above expressed method?

Comment: The syntax is `php scriptname.php arguments`. It's not clear what `artisan` and `tinker` are for.

Comment: That's not going to work. PHP needs to run the script directly to process arguments, passing it as the standard input of another script does not allow you to input arguments. It's also not clear as to what you are trying to do here? If you need to debug a script using a debugger like xdebug is probably a more effective approach

Comment: @apokryfos - If you're familiar with Laravel...tinker is a way to invoke a command line session to make use of your app code directly. So, if you look at the invocation I showed...I am invoking Laravel's tinker and then passing it a PHP script to run and wanted to pass the PHP script a numeric argument.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my point. `php` here only runs `artisan` with parameter `tinker` and with `< phpscript.php 50000` you are saying "the standard input for the running program will be read from `phpscript.php 50000`. PHP will not execute `phpscript.php 50000` so the 50000 will not be used as an input to that. Maybe something like `php artisan tinker < $(php phpscript.php 500000)` might work (depends on your terminal) to run the 2nd script and then pass the output to the 1st one but not sure if this is what you actually want.

Comment: @apokryfos - I managed to get it working by exporting an environment variable with the numeric value as received from the bash script in $2 and then had my php script do a getenv() to pick it up. Worked like a charm.